# Install a certficate on a Windows Mobile 5 device Silently

Tags: windows-mobile, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to install a certificate on a Windows Mobile device.

I have [tried creating a cab file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049506/installer-with-certficate-failing) to do it, but the cab file fails to run.

I have a lot of devices that are not all physically near me that I am going to need to put this on, so any manual process is just not feasible (ie, if it needs active sync then it is not going to work).

Any ideas on how to do this?  I have a tool that will allow me to put files and registry changes on the device, but I don't know where stuff should go to get certificate installed.

Answer (score 1):

Are these devices within a single organization? If so, you could look into [Microsoft System Center Mobile Device Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/mobile/default.mspx), which has functionality to deploy certificates to Windows Mobile devices. It's specifically aimed at managing a large number of devices within an organization.

Comment: +1 for a good idea.  But that seems to be for Windows Mobile 6.1 devices.  Sadly my devices are WM5.